# Prevent spliting lines while saving to a text file

Tags: python, csv, text, newline, md5sum

I have a json file with ~300 rows structured like this:

```
[
    {
        "OCR":"ANNA żółty LEWANDOWSKA\nHEALTHY SWEETS by Am 31\n",
        "Correct_title":...,
        "Correct_author":...,
        "Correct_ID":...
    },
    {
        "OCR":"some other\nstuff that should\nstay in same line",
        "Correct_title":...,
        "Correct_author":...,
        "Correct_ID":...
    }
]
```

Those are OCR results. Each record represents one book and I need to save only 'OCR' field but **keep newline characters embeded withing a string.**

I have then to count md5sum for each record and then, based on the last character of encoded name, save each record in one of 3 files, that is:
0-4 --> train, 5-7 --> dev-0, rest --> test-A.

Note:

- I have non ASCII characters in strings and also all newline
  characters should be saved in 'as-is' form.
- Output files **have no    extensions** - that is forced convention
  that I have no influence on.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
import hashlib
file = "data/books_OCR.json"
df_ocr = pd.read_json(file, encoding='utf-8')

for item in df_ocr['OCR']:
    line = hashlib.md5(item.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
    p_train = re.compile(r'[0-4]$')
    p_dev = re.compile(r'[5-7]$')

    # Distribute files
    if re.match(p_train, line[-1]):
        with open('gonito/train', 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
            f.write(item)
    elif re.match(p_dev, line[-1]):
        with open('gonito/dev-0', 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
            f.write(item)
    else:
        with open('gonito/test-A', 'a', encoding="utf-8", newline='') as f:
            f.write(item)
```

Expected output for instance for file *test-A* is:

```
ANNA żółty LEWANDOWSKA\nHEALTHY SWEETS by Am 31\n
some other\nstuff that should\nstay in same line
```

But instead I get:

```
ANNA LEWANDOWSKA
HEALTHY SWEETS by Am 31
some other
stuff that should
stay in same line
```

Same thing happens when I try to write records to a *.csv or *.tsv (separated with '\t') file - I get couple of lines of text (records) instead of just 1 plain line.

Is there any reasonable solution to this?

Comment: A newline is a newline. If you want to encode it somehow, you can simply `replace('\n', '\\n')` but now your representation is ambiguous if you don't also (first) replace all literal backslashes with `\\ `.

Comment: @Triplee, so perhaps I shall do it yet, while saving the json file? But doesn't it change the "meaning" of a string, that is I will have to remember to replace \\n back again to \n if I need this file for so e other task, right?@Timus thanks, I was in hurry, while writing the code, but are right.

Comment: The character sequence `\n` encodes a literal newline in JSON, but there is no escape mechanism like that in plain text. Indeed, you will need to write your own mini-format and a serializer and deserializer for it if you go this route ... but it's almost always a bad idea. Choose a standard format which lets you save data which can contain newlines if that's what you want. If JSON is not suitable, CSV (for all its flaws) has a mechanism for this, though it looks different (you basically have to quote any field which contains newlines).

Comment: @tripleee Unfortunately I **must** use such formats, as it is required by the external software. I saw this solution in CSV, i. e. _repr(item)_ would do the job, but then I have string with additional quotes on both end, which I have to remove then and that is not exactly what I want. Neverthless, I appreciate your attemp to help!

Answer (score 0):

As outlined in comments, you can easily replace a newline with `\n` if that's what you want.

One problem with this is that sequences containing literal backslashes will then be ambiguous. Does `c:\new\tmp` contain a newline (and a tab) or a literal backslash followed by a literal `n`? The proper way to disambiguate this is to backslash-escape all other backslashes, too.

```py
for item in df_ocr['OCR']:
    item = item.replace('\\', '\\\\').replace('\n', '\\n')
    ...
```

The number of backslashes here is slightly staggering, because you have to escape them from Python, too.

Designing your own mini-formats like this gets frustrating in the long run; a much more sustainable solution is to use an already-defined format like CSV (or YAML or XML or ... JSON!) so you don't have to develop and test any character-level mangling yourself, and the resulting files will be interoperable with a number of standard tools. But of course, sometimes you just don't have a choice.

Comment: ... And if you are certain that your input will never contain any literal backslashes, this code will still work, and still be robust when one day a literal backslash creeps up from behind a corner on you.